# 18.04 / login loop / Radeon Xpress 1250 (RS600M) on Samsung R60 plus laptop

Tags: 18.04

I upgraded my 16.04 to 18.04, I see the login screen, can log in and will be immediately logged out.

I know many people have this problem and searched and tried everything:
* using lightlm
* installed unity desktop
* checked for X errors
* etc.

No success. I really don't have a clue what's going on or how to even track down what's up.

Is there any workaround for this problem? Any way to track it down?

I suspect that it has to do with the graphics driver. But I didn't install anything special and the graphics card is very old. 16.04 worked... so I'm really wondering how this can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of is to install the [Oibaf AMD drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).  Since you can't login press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and log in to your account from the TTY.  Then run the following lines to install the AMD drivers for Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then reboot

Hope this helps!

Comment: You made my day! This worked for me. Thanks a lot. I wonder how anyone should come up with such a solution... For some characters, I have rendering errors for the desktop texts showing horizontal stripes (browser stuff looks always correct). Not sure what this now is but anyway...

Comment: @RobertM.Münch You're welcome!  You might have to ask another question about the horizontal lines in your texts and stuff.  It could be a compositor problem.  Different compositors can make the desktop look different and run differently.  I don't know what desktop flavor you are using.  I only use Xfce4 so I might not be much help on that one.  If you do ask a question, give as much info about it as you can like if you are using Unity, GNOME, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.