# Slow UI rendering after kernel update

Tags: 18.04, server, kernel, xorg, gui

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS + HWE (Hardware Enablement) and Openbox as a GUI. I've configured everything and it worked great. The HWE was installed via linux-generic-hwe-18.04 and xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 packages. Previously HWE used Linux kernel 5.0, but few days ago they've released a new version with newer Linux kernel 5.3.

I need to install proprietary drivers for AMD/NVIDIA GPUs on my system. The problem is that the latest AMD driver is not able to be installed on 5.3 kernel which is installed by HWE on my system. Looks like  AMD has not added a support for new kernel yet and driver installer returns an error.

So I decided to install older kernel 5.0 manually from the official website - https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.0. I've installed the kernel via deb packages, updated Grub and removed old kernels. The AMD/Nvidia drivers were also installed without errors.

But after installation the GUI starts very slow up to few minutes at first time and then lags. For example, after booting gnome-terminal may take few minutes to start and show UI. Nothing happens when I click on terminal icon and then after few minutes the terminal window appears and lags. Looks like there is something wrong with Xorg server or UI libraries. Or HWE installs some extra packages or do some speed overclocking.

I've also tried to install HWE with newer kernel and everything worked fine. Except I'm not able to install AMD drivers on new kernel 5.3.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The AMD drivers from oibaf seem to update a lot, but I have the 5.3 kernel running on my system and the drivers installed fine.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1066843/231142  As for the NVIDIA, what drivers are you installing?  I have the 440 drivers installed on another system, but I did have to build the driver into the kernel after installation.  It appears though that the NVIDIA drivers that can be installed by default with Ubuntu that installs the 390 drivers don't seem to be compatible with the 5.3 kernel.

Comment: Terrance, I'm using the latest drivers from AMD/Nvidia websites and installing them via run files or install scripts. I need to specify extra params for amdgpu-pro installer (opencl and headless for computation).

Comment: There is a good chance that the drivers from the respected sites for AMD and NVIDIA may not install properly into Ubuntu with the 5.3 kernel.  Just telling you from my experiences that sometimes the PPA installs work better than getting the drivers from the actual sites since the people maintaining the PPAs have usually gone through and made sure to get the drivers to install properly.  One draw back is that PPAs like that are usually a version or two behind.

Comment: Terrance, thanks for the advice. Maybe Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS needs to install some additional packages/libraries for better UI performance (openbox) and HWE installs them? Because previous version of HWE also used 5.0 kernel and there were not any lags.